# React Native : Cannot read property 'isConnected' of undefined (detect app connection)

Tags: javascript, react-native

I need to check user connection to internet in my app. I try to use NetInfo
but i got this error :

> Cannot read property 'isConnected' of undefined

I also add permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` file , but It did not help that.

this is my code :

```
NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then(isConnected => {
    if (isConnected) {
        this.setState({
            loading: true,
        })
        var url = 'https://api.apixu.com/v1/current'+this.state.cityname
        return fetch(url)

            .then((data) => data.json())
            .then((datajson) => {
                this.setState({
                    loading: false,
                    fetched: true,
                })
                console.log(this.state.localtime)
            })

            .catch((error) => { console.error(error) })
    } else {
        Alert.alert("You are offline!");
    }
```

What is causing this issue?

Comment: Where do you import NetInfo from? Nowadays Netinfo comes from @react-native-community

Comment: thank you so much ˙ ͜ʟ˙

Answer (score 0):

```
import {NetInfo} from 'react-native';


constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                isNetConnected: true, 
            }
        }

async componentDidMount() {
    NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener(
                'connectionChange',
                this._handleConnectivityChange

            );

            NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().done((isConnected) => {

              if(isConnected == true)
              {
                this.setState({isNetConnected: true})
              }
              else
              {
                this.setState({isNetConnected: false})
              }

            });                


        }

_handleConnectivityChange = (isConnected) => {

            if(isConnected == true)
            {
                this.setState({isNetConnected: true})
                this.getActivitiesAndNotifications()               
            }
            else
            {
                this.setState({isNetConnected: false})
            }
        };
```

Use Like this. Now if there is no any internet connection 'isNetConnected' will trigger

Comment: In fetch() callback, you can removed those if conditions and simply replace it with this.setState({isNetConnected: isConnected })